# Pandas InvalidIndexError on enumerate on custom PyTorch Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I'm trying to create a custom PyTorch dataset that will be used to train a regression model using a Pandas Dataframe. But every time I try to loop over the Dataset using DataLoader it throws an InvalidIndexError when it runs the enumerate() function. Here is the sample code:

```
batch_size = 128

class AutoMPGDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, column_names, train=False):
        self.train = train
        car_dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_file, names=column_names, na_values='?',
                                    comment='\t', sep=' ', skipinitialspace=True).dropna()
        self.train_set = car_dataframe.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=0).copy()
        self.normalize()
        self.test_set = car_dataframe.drop(self.train_set.index).copy()

    def normalize(self):
        self.train_set = (self.train_set - self.train_set.mean()) / self.train_set.std()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.train_set) if self.train else len(self.test_set)

    def __getitems__(self, idx):
        if self.train:
            # 1st column is labels, other columns are features
            return self.train_set[idx, 1:], self.train_set[idx, 0]
        else:
            return self.test_set[idx, 1:], self.test_set[idx, 0]

train_dataset = AutoMPGDataset(csv_file=url, column_names=column_names, train=True)
test_dataset = AutoMPGDataset(csv_file=url, column_names=column_names, train=False)

train_loader =  DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
test_loader =  DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
```

Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 loss_list1 = train_model(regression_model, epochs, learning_rate, 1)
      2 loss_list2 = train_model(nn_model2, epochs, learning_rate, 2)
      3 loss_list3 = train_model(nn_model3, epochs, learning_rate, 3)

Cell In[6], line 9, in train_model(model, epochs, learning_rate, network)
      7 for epoch in range(epochs):
      8     running_loss = 0.0
----> 9     for index, (features, labels) in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
     11         optimizer.zero_grad()
     13         predictions = model(features)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ciic5015/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:634, in _BaseDataLoaderIter.__next__(self)
    631 if self._sampler_iter is None:
    632     # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    633     self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 634 data = self._next_data()
    635 self._num_yielded += 1
    636 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
    637         self._IterableDataset_len_called is not None and \
    638         self._num_yielded > self._IterableDataset_len_called:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ciic5015/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:1346, in _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter._next_data(self)
...
    self._check_indexing_error(key)
  File "/Users/bermed28/opt/anaconda3/envs/ciic5015/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5925, in _check_indexing_error
    raise InvalidIndexError(key)
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: ([283, 303, 139, 254, 230, 89, 295, 233, 23, 232, 208, 72, 165, 83, 156, 142, 215, 255, 73, 178, 184, 291, 167, 84, 180, 243, 227, 100, 269, 35, 47, 154, 270, 125, 15, 93, 183, 57, 92, 311, 7, 280, 148, 119, 129, 94, 61, 144, 115, 103, 195, 204, 85, 218, 237, 24, 170, 241, 31, 202, 191, 28, 157, 256, 101, 281, 279, 6, 297, 198, 30, 21, 46, 305, 179, 49, 226, 187, 282, 247, 116, 20, 9, 296, 58, 224, 173, 248, 214, 260, 117, 8, 171, 205, 135, 14, 19, 175, 108, 76, 74, 155, 90, 27, 71, 147, 42, 149, 26, 239, 153, 286, 252, 143, 63, 192, 258, 136, 216, 290, 278, 124, 17, 309, 22, 203, 221, 174], slice(1, None, None))
```

Comment: you need to call reset_index() on both dataframes